# Keras Function (K.function) not working with RNN (code provided)

Tags: keras, output, recurrent-neural-network, keras-layer

I was trying to see the each of the layers' outputs on Keras, but I couldn't get to the correct code so I made a simple code where I was stuck at.

Question: How am I supposed to get the output of each layer where there is RNN layer in the entire layers?

You can see how I tried to see in the below code.

Here's the test code that is working(1):

```
seq_length = 3
latent_dim = 2
inputs = Input(shape=(seq_length, latent_dim))
outputs = Dense(5)(inputs)
outputs = Flatten()(outputs)

model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='mse')
print(model.summary())
```

To see the output of each layer(2):

```
layer_outputs = list()
for idx, l in enumerate(model.layers):
    if idx == 0:
        continue
    layer_outputs.append(l.output)
get_3rd_layer_output = K.function([model.layers[0].input],
                                  layer_outputs)
layer_output = get_3rd_layer_output([enc_input])
print('')
for l_output in layer_output:
    print(l_output[0][0])
    print('')
```

then the output would be something like

> [ 4.172303  -2.248884   1.397713   3.2669916  2.5788064]
>
> 4.172303

However, if I try to test the same logic as (2) with below code that uses RNN:

```
seq_length = 3
latent_dim = 2
inputs = Input(shape=(seq_length, latent_dim))
outputs, last_output = GRU(latent_dim, return_state=True, return_sequences=True)(inputs)

model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='mse')
print(model.summary())
```

and test with (2) it will emit like as follows:

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>         5     layer_outputs.append(l.output)
>         6 get_3rd_layer_output = K.function([model.layers[0].input],
>   ----> 7                                   layer_outputs)
>         8 layer_output = get_3rd_layer_output([enc_input])
>         9 print('')
>
> d:\igs_projects\nlp_nlu\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py
>   in function(inputs, outputs, updates, **kwargs)    2742
>   msg = 'Invalid argument "%s" passed to K.function with TensorFlow
>   backend' % key    2743                 raise ValueError(msg)
>   -> 2744     return Function(inputs, outputs, updates=updates, **kwargs)    2745     2746
>
> d:\igs_projects\nlp_nlu\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py
>   in **init**(self, inputs, outputs, updates, name, **session_kwargs)
>   2544         self.inputs = list(inputs)    2545         self.outputs =
>   list(outputs)
>   -> 2546         with tf.control_dependencies(self.outputs):    2547             updates_ops = []    2548             for update in updates:
>
> d:\igs_projects\nlp_nlu\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py
>   in control_dependencies(control_inputs)    5002     return
>   _NullContextmanager()    5003   else:
>   -> 5004     return get_default_graph().control_dependencies(control_inputs)    5005
>   5006
>
> d:\igs_projects\nlp_nlu\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py
>   in control_dependencies(self, control_inputs)    4541       if
>   isinstance(c, IndexedSlices):    4542         c = c.op
>   -> 4543       c = self.as_graph_element(c)    4544       if isinstance(c, Tensor):    4545         c = c.op
>
> d:\igs_projects\nlp_nlu\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py
>   in as_graph_element(self, obj, allow_tensor, allow_operation)    3488 
>   3489     with self._lock:
>   -> 3490       return self._as_graph_element_locked(obj, allow_tensor, allow_operation)    3491     3492   def _as_graph_element_locked(self,
>   obj, allow_tensor, allow_operation):
>
> d:\igs_projects\nlp_nlu\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py
>   in _as_graph_element_locked(self, obj, allow_tensor, allow_operation) 
>   3577       # We give up!    3578       raise TypeError("Can not
>   convert a %s into a %s." % (type(obj).**name**,
>   -> 3579                                                            types_str))    3580     3581   def get_operations(self):
>
> TypeError: Can not convert a list into a Tensor or Operation.

Answer (score 0):

For the GRU layer, layer.output is itself a list.

```
>>> model.layers[1].output
[<tf.Tensor 'gru_1/transpose_1:0' shape=(?, ?, 2) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'gru_1/while/Exit_3:0' shape=(?, 2) dtype=float32>]
```

layer_outputs is a list containing another list hence the error *"Can not convert a list into a Tensor or Operation"*.

```
>>> layer_outputs
[[<tf.Tensor 'gru_1/transpose_1:0' shape=(?, ?, 2) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'gru_1/while/Exit_3:0' shape=(?, 2) dtype=float32>]]
```

Updating the code like this should work:

```
get_3rd_layer_output = K.function([model.layers[0].input],
                                  layer_outputs[0]) #Extract the element and feed it.
```